# How to generate labels and use it to categorize a data frame column in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am new to Python. Still learning list comprehension. I have age as a continuous numeric variable and I need to bucketize it as 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 … 90+. I will be calling the below function. I need to do it for 100s of columns in my data with different lower, upper values, need it to be very efficient and concise. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
def createfactor(x, lower, upper, by, sep="-", above_char="+"):
    labs = []
    curr = lower
    while curr < upper - by:
        labs.append(str(curr) + sep + str(curr + by))
        curr = curr + by
    labs.append(str(upper - by) + above_char)
    y = pandas.cut(x, bins=numpy.linspace(lower,upper,upper/by+1), labels=labs)
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `pandas.cut`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"age": [4, 23, 45, 39, 76, 91, 110, 10], "x": [1,2,1,5,2,8,1,1]})

print(pd.merge(df, pd.cut(df["age"],bins=pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 10), (11, 20), (21, 30),(31,40),(41,50),(51,60),(61,70),(71,80),(81,90),(90, np.Infinity)]),right=True, include_lowest=True), left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer", suffixes=["", "_bins"]))
```

Output:

```py
age  x      age_bins
0    4  1   (0.0, 10.0]
1   23  2  (21.0, 30.0]
2   45  1  (41.0, 50.0]
3   39  5  (31.0, 40.0]
4   76  2  (71.0, 80.0]
5   91  8   (90.0, inf]
6  110  1   (90.0, inf]
7   10  1   (0.0, 10.0]

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to generate the bins and labels automatically using the lower, upper and step values I pass to a function and cannot hard code these as I have several columns that I need to work on "cut" and categorize.

Comment: Hm, for step and lower/upper bound- I would still go with the above method, with list comprehension. You can generate list of tuples with bin limits relatively easy. Check the documentation from the link - I think it might suit you.

Comment: My main issue is not the cut. It is to generate the labels instead of the default ones.